# .NET: namespace / assembly design for a COM wrapper

Tags: .net, architecture

I have a .NET project with namespace `MyCompany.InformixConnector`. I added a COM wrapper as a separate project/assembly that will only be deployed to a small number of clients. I am struggling with how to organize the projects / assemblies.

I currently have 2 assemblies: `MyCompany.InformixConnector` and `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Com`

The `.Com` assembly has a reference to the "core" assembly. However, it feels wrong having a lower-level assembly referencing a higher one.

I thought about 2 alternatives:

1. Rename the core assembly so they're both at the same level:  `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Core` and `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Com`
2. Put the COM project in a different namespace, like `MyCompany.InformixConnectorForCom`

I suppose the fundamental question is: Should a COM wrapper live in the same namespace as the code it's wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MS naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) state that there is nothing wrong for a nested namespace depend on a higher level one:

> A nested namespace should have a dependency on types in the containing
>   namespace. For example, the classes in the System.Web.UI.Design depend
>   on the classes in System.Web.UI. However, the classes in System.Web.UI
>   do not depend on the classes in System.Web.UI.Design.

The same logic could be applied to the assembly naming. In your particular case I would put core functionality into `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Core` namespace and assembly, that would explicitly indicate where the common stuff is.

Then create a namespace for interoperability `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Interop` and put there all the generic stuff needed for dealing with com and other 3d party stuff. If there is no such stuff you can skip it and add it as needed.

Then create a namespace and assembly for your com wrapper `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Interop.Com`. This assembly would reference `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Core` and `MyCompany.InformixConnector.Interop` (if needed).

Comment: I like that very much. Thank you.